# Template parameters that require deduced argument *before* user arguments

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I have a function where I'd like the arguments partially-deduced and the remaining, mostly non-type arguments, are given by the user (as a way of enforcing them being given at compile-time). However, the type of this non-type user-sourced argument is deduced, therefor it must come before the user arguments. That breaks the ability of the user to have the first argument deduced. I have a small example below, that does not compile, demonstrating what I'm talking about.

```
template <typename T, T N>
class int_const {};

template <typename T, T M, T N>
auto add(int_const<T, N> a) {
    return int_const<T, N + M>();
}

int main(void) {
    int_const<int, 1> a;
    add<32>(a); 
    // add<int, 32>(a); does compile, but requires the user to know or extract that first argument
    return 0;
}
```

Is there anyway to support the template function call as it is seen in `main()`?

Comment: As alternative, create member: `a.add<42>()`. (`T` would be fixed in the class).

Comment: @Jarod42 I have thought about that, but the rest of my library uses free-functions and making this one function a member function kind of breaks the consistency. I can't seem to find any way to abuse that fact either.

Comment: There is also `template <typename T, T M, T N> auto add(int_const<T, M>, int_const<T, N>)`. With [UDL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal), you might even do something like `add(32_ic, a)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use C++17, you can use `auto` for `M` value

```
template <auto M, typename T, T N>
auto add(int_const<T, N> a) {
    return int_const<T, N + M>();
}
```

So you can call it as follows

```
add<32>(a);
```

Before C++17... well, I don't see a way without explicating also the type.

As pointed by Jarod42, `auto M` intercept also values of different types.

If you want impose that the type of `M` is **exactly** `T`, you can use SFINAE; by example, as follows

```
template <auto M, typename T, T N, 
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, decltype(M)>, bool> = true>
auto add(int_const<T, N> a) {
    return int_const<T, N + M>();
}
```

So you get errors from

```
add<32u>(a);
add<short{32}>(a);
```

But maybe you can relax the requirement and accept also that `decltype(M)` isn't exactly `T` but also simply that `M` is narrowing convertible to `T`.

Maybe

```
template <auto M, typename T, T N>
auto add(int_const<T, N> a) {
    return int_const<T, N + T{M}>();
} // .......................^^^^
```

so

```
add<32u>(a);
add<short{32}>(a);
```

are compiled because `32u` and `short{32}` are narrowing convertible to `int` where

```
add<(unsigned long)(-1)>(a);
```

gives a compilation error because `(unsigned long)(-1)` (usually the bigger possible value for an `unsigned long`) can't be narrowed to `int`.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It's unfortunate there is no solution pre-C++17, I'm (unfortunately) targeting C++11 and 14. I guess I'll have to design around the problem.

Comment: Notice that you loose the restriction that `decltype(M)` is `T` (which might be fixed by SFINAE if needed).

Comment: @Jarod42 - Right; but could be that it's enough to require that `M` is narrowing convertible to `T`. Answer improved.

Comment: @ktb - it's a pity you can't use C++17; I've improved the answer (following a suggestion from Jarod42) but, unfortunately, the improvement regard the C++17 solution.

Comment: I have this solution marked for implementation if C++17 becomes a viable target for my project, but in the mean time I decided to go with making the function in question a member function so that it can use the class's template definition of the type `T`.